# Why is the system log viewer blank?

Tags: log

Why is the system log viewer in unity 11.10 blank and there is  no possibility to add any path to log files? this empty useless window must have an equivalent (which?) but why developers put it into the dash? I have very fresh installation of the 64 bit system. Could it be a bug? My previous installation of the same system had the same issue. [screenshot](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=24990)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-utils/+bug/841085

I see no posted solution other then viewing the logs in a terminal.

Sorry you are having this problem, bugs happen, please be kind to the developers, we need them to help find a solution.